# Can't end program with break. Break is used inside defined function and function is later used inside while loop. What can I do?

Tags: python

I need a help with a certain situation.

We have the following code:

```
import random
Genre = ["Power metal", "Melodic death metal", "Progressive metal", "Rock"]
Power_metal = ["Helloween", "Dragonforce", "Hammerfall"]
Melodic_death_metal = ["Kalmah", "Insomnium", "Ensiferum", "Wintersun"]
Progressive_metal = ["Dream theater", "Symphony X"]
Rock = ["Bon Jovi", "Nirvana"]

a = ["Pumpkins united", "Halloween"]

Helloween = set(a)

Music = input("\nSelect a music genre from available: %s:" % (Genre))
def bands(Music):
    while True:
        if Music == "Melodic death metal":
            return (Melodic_death_metal)
        elif Music == "Power metal":
            return (Power_metal)
        elif Music == "Progressive metal":
            return (Progressive_metal)
        elif Music == "Rock":
            return (Rock)
        else:
            Music = input("\nYou entered the wrong name. Please, enter again: %s:" % (Genre))

Band = input("\nReffering to chosen genre, I have bands such as: %s. Choose a specific band and I'll suggest a random song:\n" % bands(Music))
def fate(Band):
    while True:
        if Band == "Helloween":
            if len(Helloween) != 0:
                print("Suggested song: ", Helloween.pop())
                break
            elif len(Helloween) == 0:
                print("I don't have more songs to propose. Enjoy your music")
                break

fate(Band)

while True:
    next = input("\nWould you like me to suggest one more song from the band of your choice ?  Answer yes or no:\n")
    if next == "no":
        print("Enjoy your music")
        break
    elif next == "yes":
        fate(Band)
```

The problem is: when we get to the point where the program has no more songs to offer, it should print: `"I don't have more songs to propose. Enjoy your music"`and break. But instead of this, it goes all the way to the last loop and doesn't end until I type in the console `no`.

Can I make somehow the statement inside loop to end program even if I type in console `yes`?

Cause it will keep printing:

```
I don't have more songs to propose. Enjoy your music.

Would you like me to suggest one more song from the band of your choice ?  Answer yes or no:
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can return from your function, instead of breaking out of the while loop in the function. The effect is the same.

Comment: Return a bool from your function to indicate to the caller to stop program

Comment: With that return, however, you can return a value. For example, a boolean: `True` for continuing the outer main loop, `False` for not continuing. In that case, you'd call your function as follows: `if not fate(Band): break`. So depending on what the function returned, you continue in the outer loop, or you quit also the outer loop.

Comment: I found out, that instead of `break`, simple `quit()` helps too.